# str_replace within a mutate over a list or a dataset in R

Tags: r, str-replace, purrr, dplyr

I'd like to add a charecter into a rows within a dataset based on another dataset. So I have two datasets one called emails and the other called domains. My problem is that the email dataset is missing the @ character that separates the username from the domain name and I need to add it based on the domains dataset.

Here are my two datasets:

```
emails<-c("tjoeblogymail.com",                   
"simonsaysgmail.com"  ,             
"realpeoplehsne.com",                   
"funnythingsraveis.com") %>%
  as_tibble() %>% rename(email = value)
```

Which results in:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 1
  email                      
  <chr>                      
1 tjoeblogymail.com      
2 simonsaysgmail.com  
3 realpeoplehsne.com      
4 funnythingsraveis.com
```

Domains:

```
domains<-c("ymail.com",                   
        "gmail.com"  ,             
        "hhsne.com",                   
        "raveis.com") %>%
  as_tibble()  %>% rename(domain = value)
```

Which results in:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 1
  domain    
  <chr>     
1 ymail.com 
2 gmail.com 
3 hhsne.com 
4 raveis.com
```

I'd like to add an @ sign into the string before the domain. Currently, I can do this one by one as follows:

```
emails %>%
  mutate(email =  str_replace(email, "gmail.com", "@gmail.com"),
         email =  str_replace(email, "ymail.com", "@ymail.com"),
         email =  str_replace(email, "hsne.com", "@hsne.com"),
         email =  str_replace(email, "raveis.com", "@raveis.com"))
```

Which results in:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 1
  email                       
  <chr>                       
1 tjoeblog@ymail.com      
2 simonsays@gmail.com  
3 realpeople@hsne.com      
4 funnythings@raveis.com
```

However, I'd like to be able to do this in a way that does not require me to have to cut and paste each email address into a `mutate` and `str_replace` but rather use a `map` or `apply` function and cannot figure out how to do it. Any advice/help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You could paste all the domains in one string and use `str_replace_all`

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(emails$email, str_c(domains$domain, collapse = "|"), 
          function(m) paste0('@', m))

#[1] "tjoeblog@ymail.com"     "simonsays@gmail.com"    "realpeople@hsne.com"   
#      "funnythings@raveis.com"
```

Removed one extra "h" from "hhsne.com" in `domains` dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Use a map function to iterate over your domains

```
library(tidyverse)
emails %>% 
  mutate(email = map_chr(domains$domain, ~{str_replace(email, 
                                                       .x, 
                                                       paste0("@", .x)) %>% 
  str_subset(., "@")}))
```